# How do you create an MSI for an MFC Active X in Visual Studio

Tags: mfc, windows-installer

Can someone please explain to me a simple way of creating an MSI for an MFC Active X control, which can if possible register the control on the workstation?

Thanks

Comment: I've never used MSI, but isn't it just a matter of placing the DLL into a directory and calling REGSVR32 on it? It should be pretty simple.

Comment: Actually MSI takes the opposite approach as it's a declarative programming language not imperative.  Calling DllRegisterServer() is considered out of process and fragile.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer ( .MSI ) is an SDK.  In general the best practice is to use the COM / Registry tables and not go out of process via the SelfReg table or any other technique ( e.g. Regsvr32 ) that calls DllRegisterServer().

However it's impossible to tell you exactly how to do it without some knowledge of which authoring tool(s)  you are using to generate your MSI database.

Answer (score 0):

In the solution that contains your ActiveX control project:

Right-click on the Solution, choose Add -> New Project.  Choose "Setup Project"

Right-click on the new Setup project, choose Add, then Project Output.

Select Primary Output from your ActiveX control project.

Under your Setup project, right-click on "Primary Output from..." and choose Properties.

Set the **Register** property to **vsdrpCOMSelfReg**

(Tested with Visual Studio 2010)